# image onload event not firing

Tags: javascript

Should this work?

```
<script type=text/javascript>

    function load_i () {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = load_e();
        img.src = "whatever.jpg";
    }

    function load_e() { alert("loaded"); }

</script>
```

Right now the image gets loaded, but apparently the onload event isn't being triggered. 
Tried it in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change:

```
img.onload = load_e();
```

to:

```
img.onload = load_e;
```

---

With the following line:

```
img.onload = load_e();
```

You're calling `load_e` and assigning the result, `undefined`, to `img.onload`.

Comment: Thanks Xander! Silly me, you're right. 


But I also tried  onload=load_e, onload=function () { alert (x); }  and it doesn't work either. There must be something wrong with my page somewhere else. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The problem had nothing to do with the event not firing - it was a stupid bug on my part. Sorry about it and thanks again!